# jQuery: physical click on one siblings child to trigger virtual click on other siblings child

Tags: jquery

Im trying and trying to get my script to work, but I just cant.. Here's my code:

HTML: http://pastebin.com/5s2n2C4X

jQuery: http://pastebin.com/Xh0dAy6A

The problem: It's for a portfolio. When I click the item trigger, a popupanimation is triggered to display the info about that specific item. I want to add arrows (trigger next/prev item (line 51-57 jQuery)). As it is right now, I can without any trouble click on the actual item trigger and get the project that I clicked on. When that is showing, I can click on the other items, and it then closes the current window and opens the new one. Perfect, just the way I want it. But.. If I, god forbid, click on the arrows it simply won't work. It closes the current window (like it should), and opens the new one (like it should) for just a couple of milliseconds before closing it straight away (not the way it should be..).

Does anyone have a clue as how to solve this extremely irritating problem? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Instead of triggering the click event, why not move the code that loads the popup content into the popup container into its own function?  Then, when the user clicks next or prev, simply call the function to load new content into the popup, instead of going through the whole process of closing one popup and opening another.

Comment: I think you might have to see it to understand.. Hope this works: http://minimyran.mine.nu/cm4/wp/

Comment: Your page doesn't appear to be working - clicking on the arrows just hides the popup.

Comment: Yes, thats what im trying to fix :( I tried your post but it doesnt seem to fit my needs unfortionatly..

Comment: Well, it's only a barebones example.  You'd need to adapt it to move your popup window around, etc.

Comment: Okay. But do you think there's any chance of getting my script to work? :(

Comment: Probably.  You'll need to debug the code (http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tut_debugging.html) and see what's causing the new window to immediately close.

Comment: I know its the last function, siblings click. Ill try that, thank you!

Comment: Well.. I dont seem to get the debugger..

Answer (score 0):

When all you want to do is change what is displayed in the popup, you should do that, rather than go through the process of first closing the current popup, then opening a new one.

Here is an extremely simplified example of doing that:

http://jsfiddle.net/7jK4t/

Comment: I don't think this will work. Atleast I cannot see how it would. I cant have a static box to which the content loads :(